# Many-To-Many Recursive Relationship Without a Primary Entity

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have had multiple needs for a linking table for recursive relationships where one record is not a clear "parent" record over the other.  Here is an example that I hope makes my issue as visceral as I can display or explain it:

```
(Person)
Id   Person
-------------
1    Bob
2    Sue
```

If Sue was Bob's mother it would be reasonable to use the Relationship table as such:

```
(Relationship)
PersonId1    PersonId2    Relationship
----------------------------------------
2            1            Mother/Son
```

But if they are cousins it could be either:

```
(Relationship)
PersonId1    PersonId2    Relationship
-----------------------------------------
2            1            Cousin/Cousin
```

OR

```
(Relationship)
PersonId1    PersonId2    Relationship
---------------------------------------
1            2            Cousin/Cousin
```

This is....ugly....and would require constant ORs or UNIONS in joins and where clauses.

The following seems clean but very verbose but maybe there's nothing better:

```
(Relationship)
Id    Type
----------------------
1     Cousin/Cousin

(Relationship_Person)
RelationshipId    PersonId
---------------------------
1                 1
1                 2
```

Is there a better pattern?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this should be a comment, but I think in the first case you should have two rows:

```
PersonId1    PersonId2    Relationship
---------------------------------------
1            2            Son
2            1            Mother
```

Then it makes more sense to have:

```
PersonId1    PersonId2    Relationship
---------------------------------------
1            2            Cousin
2            1            Cousin
```

Comment: Gordon at first when I saw your comment I thought yeah well duh that's the ugliness of my issue.  BUT even though it feels like the Department of Redundancy Department and would be the wrong answer on every college test.....I think it might be the right K.I.S.S. answer even if it breaks numerous normalization rules.  Thank you I'm surprised/shocked I'm considering this!

Answer (score 0):

You need three key values, one for the Person (PID), one for the Relationship Type (RTID) and one to group the relationships together (RID).

```
RID     RTID              PID
1       1 (Mother)        1 (Mary)
1       2 (Son)           2 (Joe)
2       3 (Cousin)        2 (Joe)
2       3                 3 (Sue)
2       3                 4 (Carl)
1       2 (Son)           5 (Chris)
1       4 (Daughter)      6 (Kathy)
2       3 (Cousin)        5 (Chris)
2       3                 6 (Kathy)
1       5 (Father)        7 (Rick)
```

Once a new relationship group is established, it is simple to add new members to the relationship without affecting the other members and you don't have the Cartesian product in unbounded relationships like cousins.  Each person will have one row for each relationship they participate in, regardless of the number of members of that relationship.

You may also want to consider effective & expiration dates to handle birth/death and marriage/divorce.

Comment: Thank you Wes for taking so much time to cleanly restate more explicitly my second train-of-thought imaginary example.  I'm still hoping somehow someone might have a more simple linking pattern, but it may not (or even probably not) exist.

Comment: (Person) -> (RelationshipPersonLink) -> (Relationship) -> (RelationshipPersonLink) -> (Person) is just so many "hops" to see all that are connected.  I certainly realize I can put this into a view and pin-point the perfect indexing for it.....

Comment: In this imaginary "family" example it doesn't seem like a big deal, but if I'm drilling down a up to a dozen or so relationship layers to see all connected components using a four-hop many-to-many link recursion in a single call applying this pattern in other uses it feels ..... heavy?...er...inefficient?...umm....complicated.  I know, those are terribly unscientific explanations.